# Latent change score model with observed variables

Tags: r-lavaan, sem

my professor wants me to calculate a latent change score model for my masters thesis.

Since my model does not include any latent variables, I was wondering if I can just calculate the model using my observed variables with the lavaan package.

Would be grateful for some help!